# Example of a brick-infinite, tame, triangular algebra of global dimension$\geq3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, quiver

I'm trying to compute some examples and I'm unable to come up with a following example:

What is(are) the example(s) of an acyclic quiver $Q$ with relations such that the 2-Kronecker quiver is NOT a sub-quiver of $Q$ and the corresponding finite-dimensional algebra $A=\mathbb{K}Q/I$, where $I\subseteq\mathbb{K}Q$ is an admissible ideal of relations of the quiver $Q$ and $\mathbb{K}$ is an algebraically closed field, is a tame, triangular algebra of global dimension at least $3$ and is brick-infinite(i.e., $A-\operatorname{mod}$ has infinitely many bricks, up to isomorphism)?

Edit: triangular means that the quiver $Q$ is acyclic. An element $M\in A-\operatorname{mod}$ is called a brick if $\operatorname{End}_{A}(M)\cong\mathbb{K}$.

Comment: Cross-posted at MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/431613/338456